# Saving double values in char[] buffer

Tags: c, double, buffer

I try to write program whitch uses stack for present some kind of data (char, double or string).

```
char *data_buffer;
double n;
...
data_buffer = (char*)malloc(4096 * sizeof(char));
...
*(data_buffer + buffer_top) = n; //buffer_top - just offset for first byte
...
printf("%f ", (double)*(data_buffer + buffer_top));
```

Variables data_buffer and buffer_top correct.
But output is strange. It correct only if n < 127.
Why could it be?

P.S. I don't want to change type of data_buffer becase it includes also char and string of different lengths.

Example of work (!! - test output of n before write it to buffer:

```
126 //push
!! 1.260000e+02 
127 // push
!! 1.270000e+02   
128 // push
!! 1.280000e+02 
. // pop
-128.000000 //error
. //pop
127.000000  //ok
. //pop
126.000000  //ok
123456 // push
!! 1.234560e+05 
. //pop
64.000000 //error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both lines are missing a cast to `(double *)`, so they do a `char` assignment and a read, respectively. Here's what your code is actually doing with some explicit `(char)` casts added to highlight the incorrect type conversions.

```
*(data_buffer + buffer_top) = (char) n;
...
printf("%f ", (double) (char) *(data_buffer + buffer_top));
```

What you want is:

```
*((double *) (data_buffer + buffer_top)) = n;
...
printf("%f ", *((double *) (data_buffer + buffer_top)));
```

Comment: Unless `buffer_top` is known to be a multiple of the alignment requirement of `double`, these operations should be implemented by copying bytes between the buffer and a temporary `double` object. As written, this can can have behavior undefined by the C standard.